# Split string using Regex and indexOf

Tags: java, string, split, substring, indexof

I have a simple string Ex. `1.0.0.2` and I want to split and retrieve only part of the string:
output: `1.0.0` basically I want to remove all text after the third `.` included. I tried with `split()` function, count the occurrances of `.` and, if greater than 2, get the `indexOf()` third point and `substring()`. Is there an easier or faster method to achieve this? Maybe using **regEx**?

Edit:
I don't know how many dots there will be.

Comment: Do you know that there will be exactly three dots? If so, then `lastIndexOf()` will probably be more helpful than `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know for sure that there will be exactly three dots — so you can't use `lastIndexOf()` — then here is a regex-based solution:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^[^.]*(?:[.][^.]*){0,2}").matcher(input);
m.find(); // guaranteed to be true for this regex
final String output = m.group(0);
```

Comment: +1 for the lovely usage of group(0) and the non-capturing group. Elegant.

Comment: Thank you @ruakh. Can you explain the literal meaning of the regex? I understand that: `{0,2}` means how many times find the expression. The beginning `^[^.]*` : start with any char but . (and it's facultative - star key). The middle group `(?:[.][^.]*)` means?

Comment: @StarsSky: `(?:...)` is a grouping construct, so that the `{0,2}` will apply to the whole of `[.][^.]*`, instead of just the last part. `[.]` means "any of these characters: `.`". (I'm abusing the fact that `.` has no special meaning inside a character class, so `[.]` is a way of escaping it. It's more correct to write `\\.`, but I find `[.]` to be more readable.) So `(?:[.][^.]*)` means "a dot, followed by zero or more non-dot characters".

Answer (score 3):

It's simple and fast to do this using only `substring` and `lastIndexOf`. I think the code is quite readable:

```
String str = "1.0.0.1";
String output = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Although you can achieve the same with a regex, I wouldn't bother, it's a lot more verbose, harder to understand (takes you a while longer at least), and this is quite fast for a resonable sized `String`.

**edit**

In case you don't know how many dots your `String` will have you need a more complex approach, and in that case, a regex would do fine, +ruakh's answer does the trick quite nicely.

If you prefer more readability (readability depends on your confort around regexes, of course), you can create an auxiliary method that counts the number of occurrences of a character in a string, and use that to decide if you should chop it or not.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it AND even included a nice description and explanation of _why_ a regex would be overkill here. Nice!

Comment: It's just a question of luck with the page refreshes eheh.

Comment: IMHO regex is necessary, as we don't know how many dots there will be. This only works if there are three dots, if there are any more or less you won't cut of the input after (including) the third dot.

Comment: You're right jlordo, I read the question a bit too fast, edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "1.0.0.2";
String output = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf("."));
```